# "Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15" whenever importing on background.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to import functions and primitives (using modules) from my index.js file onto background.js for a Google extension that  I'm making, but then it hits me with "Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15" as soon as I do so. Removing that section 'import { searchTransform, inputLang} from "./index.js";' immediately gets me "worker service active".
I have tried playing around with changing the  tag properties; I added "module" to my manifest and on the html file. I updated chrome to the most recent version.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This code means the script has an error. A typical mistake is using `window` or `document` or `eval`.

Comment: In my case, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70843507/3809427 is the solution.